# d3 make a group draggable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to call a dram function on the internal div element and I want the parent `<g>` and its content to be dragged. How can this be achieved?

I guess this does not work because `<g>` is only a grouping element and not a container.

The transorm works but it acts funny, why?

```
<g  id="input-container">  
    <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="200" height="400" id="input-container-fo" class="container-fo">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="input-container-div" class="container-div">
            <div class="container-div-title" id="input-container-div-title">Input</div>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
<script>
    var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
                           .on("start", function () {
                              })
                           .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                                   var x = d3.event.x;
                                   var y = d3.event.y;
                                   //  d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                                   d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr("x",x).attr("y",y);
                                            })
                           .on("end", function () {

                                            });
    d3.select("#output-container-div").call(dragcontainer);
</script>
```

Comment: `this.parentNode.parentNode`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: You have some other problem, because it works.

Comment: yes I had a different problem, I will update the problem soon

Comment: Now I can see your problem: g elements *don't have* x or y positions. You'll have to *translate* it.

Comment: The translate acts funny - flickering and sometime disappearing. I have no idea why. In this JSFidle I tried to demonstrate it but the rectangle won't display. https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/8d6ht3dL/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122720/discussion-between-sachdan-and-gerardo-furtado).

Answer (score 1):

```
<g  id="input-container">  
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="200" height="400" id="input-container-fo" class="container-fo">
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="input-container-div" class="container-div">
   <div class="container-div-title" id="input-container-div-title">Input</div>
   </div>
 </foreignObject>
</g>
```

If "container-div-title" is the division where event is being occurred then you should try

```
this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
```

in not the just remove parentElement for appropriate event occurring elements